# How to use "RAISE INFO, RAISE LOG, RAISE DEBUG, PERFORM” in PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql

I have script in Oracle procedure as Pragma autonomous_transaction:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "CIDR_STAGING"."PR_WRITE_ERROR_LOG" is
        PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
   insert into cidrmgmt.errorlog(
                         tstamp, os_user,host,module,errorcode,errormsg)
        values
                (sysdate, v_os_user, v_host, v_module, v_ErrorCode, v_ErrorMsg );
        commit;
end;
/
```

and another procedure to call transaction procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "CIDR_STAGING"."PR_MIG_STG_FORMS" ( v_Ret OUT number )
as
        v_ErrorCode             number;
        v_ErrorMsg              varchar2(512);
        v_Module                        varchar2(32) := 'PR_MIG_STG_FORMS';
begin

        ----
        -- Simply delete the data from production table
        ----
        delete from cidrdba.ref_forms where 1=1;

        ----
        -- Simply copy the data from staging into production
        ----
        insert into cidrdba.ref_forms(
           form_number, form_title, mig_filename
                )
                select form_number, form_title, mig_filename
                from cidr_staging.stg_ref_forms;
        ----
        -- Set the return code to 0
        ----
        v_Ret := SQLCODE;

----
-- Exception error handler
----
exception
        when others then
                v_ErrorCode := SQLCODE;
                v_ErrorMsg  := SQLERRM;
                v_Ret       := v_ErrorCode;

                ----
                -- Commit the record into the ErrorLog
                ----
                pr_write_error_log( sys_context('userenv','session_user'),
                    sys_context('userenv','host'), v_Module,
                         v_ErrorCode, v_ErrorMsg );
        ----
        -- Intentionally leaving the "commit" to application
        ----
end;
/
```

and I converted it to Postgres Pragma autonomous_transaction and I'm not sure its corrected but it didn't give any error.

```
create or replace FUNCTION "PR_WRITE_ERROR_LOG" ( v_os_user IN varchar(4000), v_host IN
 varchar(4000), v_module IN varchar(4000), v_errorcode IN int, v_errormsg IN varchar(4000) ) 
 RETURNS VOID 
as $$

BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
   insert into cidrmgmt.errorlog(
                         tstamp, os_user,host,module,errorcode,errormsg)
        values
                (current_timestamp, v_os_user, v_host, v_module, v_ErrorCode, v_ErrorMsg );

        /* commit; */

end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CIDR_STAGING"."PR_MIG_STG_FORMS" ( v_Ret OUT int ) RETURNS integer
as $$
declare
        v_ErrorCode             int;
        v_ErrorMsg              varchar(512);
        v_Module                varchar(32) = 'PR_MIG_STG_FORMS';

begin
        ----
        -- Simply delete the data from production table
        ----
        delete from cidrdba.ref_forms where 1=1;

        ----
        -- Simply copy the data from staging into production
        ----
        insert into cidrdba.ref_forms(
           form_number, form_title, mig_filename
                )
                select form_number, form_title, mig_filename
                from cidr_staging.stg_ref_forms;
        ----
        -- Set the return code to 0
        ----
        v_Ret := SQLCODE;

----
-- Exception error handler
----
exception
        when others then
                v_ErrorCode := SQLCODE;
                v_ErrorMsg  := SQLERRM;
                v_Ret       := v_ErrorCode;

                ----
                -- Commit the record into the ErrorLog
                ----
        **RAISE NOTICE 'Calling "CIDR_STAGING"."PR_WRITE_ERROR_LOG"(%)', ( sys_context('userenv','session_user'),
        sys_context('userenv','host'), v_Module,
        v_ErrorCode, v_ErrorMsg );**

or
**PERFORM pr_write_error_log( sys_context('userenv','session_user'),
                    sys_context('userenv','host'), v_Module,
                         v_ErrorCode, v_ErrorMsg );
        -- Intentionally leaving the "commit" to application**
        ----
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and how should I execute another function within the function like Oracle?  I have searched and found parameters raise log, raise info, raise before and perform.  I want to understand how to call the function w/in a function like Oracle would you please explain it?

Comment: `raise` has nothing to do with executing a function. To execute a function use [`perform function_name()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT)  if you want to discard the result or assign the result to a variable `some_var := some_function()`

Comment: You can not use use `start transcation`, `commit` or `rollback` inside a function. You need a stored procedure for that  - which is only available since Postgres 11

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190731) for a way to mimic autonomous transactions in Postgres for logging purposes.